# Use a layout_height of 0dip instead of wrap_content for better performance.....how to remove this warning

Tags: android, android-layout

How to remove this warning?

**Use a layout_height of 0dip instead of wrap_content for better performance**

Comment: Um...set layout_height to 0dp? Or perhaps remove the layout_weight attribute (which I'm guessing you are using). Without seeing your layout file, there's nothing more anyone can suggest.

Comment: If you are seeing that warning, 99% times you can safely make the change and it doesn't break your layout.

Answer (score 24):

Ok let me explain through an example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Hello World!!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the above example I am using `android:layout_weight="1"` for TextView by which I am telling the layout that my TextView will take the full height as of parent layout(LinearLayout). So, in that case `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` is of no use as the `TextView` will have the full size as parent `LinearLayout`. So, in that case its better to add `android:layout_height="0dp"` to make TextView wrap itself to the height of parent Layout.

Comment: thanx bro i got it now thanx alot

Answer (score 0):

You must have use `layout_weight` attribute in child element which is present in vertical parent layout.So in that case you have already told parent how much height is to be applied to child.

So in child element replace

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

with

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

However, this is just a guess and you should post your entire layout XML

Answer (score 0):

If you have any value specified for `layout_weight`, **even if it is set to 0** it will throw this warning.

The problem is, that setting height/width it to 0dp, in this case results in the element not being shown at all. Just remove the `layout_weight` parameter and all is well.

Of course as many others said, this is not a problem if you have a `layout_weight` greater than zero specified. Just set `layout_height` or `layout_width` (depending on the layout) to 0dp.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem, so...

Make sure parent Layout's orientation is set matching the direction you want the weightSum to correspond.

In other words, make sure the parent Layout's orientation is set to "horizontal" if it is the layout_width of a child View that you want to use weightSum with.

Or alternatively:

Set the parent's Layout orientation to vertical if it is the childs layout_height attribute you want to use weightSum with.